# Little Icons and Font Size is coming little small

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

JMeter icons and text is coming too small. Tried with 2 versions 5.4.1 & 5.2.1 as well.
Text font size is smaller wants little bigger so that it can be readable easily.

Comment: Try Options -> Zoom In